# Landscape-oriented table over multiple pages

Tags: longtable, rotating

I would like to spread my vertical table over multiple pages.
I tried it with `sidewaystable` and `longtable`, but that put everything on one page. Another idea would be just to create x tables, where x stands for the number of needed pages. That would work, but I would like to have a more convenient solution. Is there any?

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4,]{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable}            
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

   \begin{sidewaystable}
      \begin{longtable}[c]{|p{5cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
         \hline
          0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
          \hline
      \end{longtable}
   \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: replace `sidewaystable` by `landscape` and add `lscape` or `pdflscape` package

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! I'm a bit confused by your question. Your example involves a table which does not need `longtable` at all because it only has one row. And it will surely fit on one page horizontally, too. Is your actual table (i) too long (ii) too wide or (iii) both? Are you rotating it because it is too wide for portrait but fits in landscape mode? If so, the trick would be to use something other than `sidewaystable` which will prevent page breaks. Switching to landscape mode would let you do this, for example.

Comment: @cfr: I left out the lines which would overflow the page because I thought it isn't necessary and just complicates my code. My current table is too wide for horizontal and too long for one vertical page. I will try the landscape mode

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `sidewaystable` environment does not let you split its contents across multiple pages. Since you're using a `longtable` environment, which has its own `\caption` commands, etc., there's no real need to embed it in a `sidewaystable` environment anyway. Instead, consider loading the `pdflscape` package and using that package's `landscape` environment to rotate the material by 90 degrees.

```
\documentclass[11pt,paper=a4]{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable} % for 'longtable' environment
\usepackage{pdflscape} % for 'landscape' environment
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\section{World}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ | p{5cm} | *{15}{c|} }
\hline\endhead  % header material
\hline\endfoot  % footer material
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address a comment by @pauljohn32: If the `longtable` and `pdflscape` packages are loaded and if a halfway-competent pdf viewer is in use, the `landscape`/`longtable` combination (a) rotates the tabular material 90 degrees counterclockwise to landscape format and (b) ensures that the *onscreen display* of the pages with the tabular material is also rotated, so that readers don't have to crane their necks in order to take in the tabular information. However, this combination does *not* make the pages into "landscape pages"; i.e., the header and footer lines are still placed where they'd go in portrait mode. In the following screenshot, I've highlighted the MWE's header and footer lines in yellow to demonstrate this fact. (Of course, *what exactly* is placed on the header and footer lines depends on factors such as the document class in use. However, that's a separate issue, isn't it?)

[image]

Comment: (I would put this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation) @Mico 's solution didn't work for my until I changed:`\usepackage{pdflscape}` to `\usepackage{lscape}`

Comment: @LabviewMustDie - In order for your comment to be (more) helpful to future readers of this posting and, in particular, for readers to understand readily why you found it was necessary to switch from the `pdflscape` package to the `lscape` package,  you should provide some extra information about your computing environment. E.g., which engine do you use to compile your documents: pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX? And, which document class do you employ?

Comment: We ran into a problem with this answer at our University.  The rules for dissertation forbid any landscape pages. It is OK to rotate a table, but if the page itself becomes landscape, then it is rejected.  I've not found any solution that allows longtable with rotated table.

Comment: @pauljohn32 - Please see the addendum I posted to address your comment.

Comment: Regarding @pauljohn32 's comment and the edit to the answer, is there a way to get the footer where it would be for a landscape page?

Comment: @climatestudent - Please clarify what you mean by "get the footer where it would be for a landscape page". Please also state which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico, sorry, I mean to place the footer at the bottom of the page, when viewed in landscape orientation, which would be the right-hand long edge in portrait orientation. I'm using the `report` document class, with options `a4paper, 12pt`, in case that matters.

Comment: @climatestudent - Speaking for myself, I find it difficult to read a document in which the positions of the page headers and footers bounce around according to whether the page is typeset in portrait or landscape mode. Can you arrange to suppress the footer(s) on the landscape-oriented pages?

Comment: @Mico, thanks, fair enough, for my part I find it hard to read a page in which some text is oriented in a direction orthogonal to the majority of the text. Yes, I have removed the footers, but this leads to a somewhat excessive (and unsightly) left margin (when the page is viewed in landscape orientation). But this is a different concern, for which I will try to find a solution. Thank you for the rapid responses!