# Table printed accross two facing pages in booklet

Tags: tables

I am working on A5-sized workbook where I would like to place a few A4-sized tables across facing pages (it will be also printed in the inner margin areas, unlike normal pages). I am considering to do a macro producing the table and use absolute positioning (via TikZ) to put it once on the page left (overflowing the right page margin) and once on the page right (the upper left corner of the box being beyond the left page margin).

Please note this question is not about longtable &c breaking across pages.

Is it elegant? Is there some more simple approach?

**EDIT:** the table is to be filled by hand, whence the size requirement. The width can be set exactly, it is produced via `tabu` spread to the required width.

Comment: It would be easier, if you could give us a minimal code example to play with. A problem of your approach: a table that's not exactly of that width (hence the question whether you always use something tabularx-like?), because the overflow created by anchoring at top-left may very.

Comment: you should thing about font size i table, if you like to fit on a half space. probably it would be better to spread it over two pages as `longtable`.

Comment: @Zarko: thanks for comments, I added the information at the end of the post.

Comment: @eudoxos, sorry, your question is not very clear (without see example of your document with this table). temporary  it seems that question is opinion based and probably will be as such closed.

Comment: If this book is to be printed, then you really don't want to fill up the entire inner margin to the edge of the page, since the edges will disappear in the spine. Using longtable in landscape mode seems to be a better option - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242015/landscape-oriented-table-over-multiple-pages

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: it will be a stapled booklet, so it will open all way to the spine. Thanks for the link.